# in sinatra using erubis, default setting escape_html is true. sometimes hava to unescape

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb, erubis

In Sinatra, using erubis, the default setting for `escape_html` is `true`.

But sometimes I want to to unescape, because, I do not want to add too much escape_html. Don't repeat yourself. :)

`helpers:`

```
def raw(string)
  CGI::unescape_html(string)
end
```

`views:`

```
<div class="body">
  <%= raw "<h1>Thanks for help...</h1>" %>
</div>
```

does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about which version of Erubis you use, but it [seems like](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.03.html#escape-enhancer) it has a special kind of tag for that particular case: with **two** equals signs. So the line from your example might look like:

```
<%== "<h1>Thanks for help...</h1>" %>
```

Calling to `CGI::unescape` should not be necessary, because the string is initially not escaped. All you need is to *prevent* escaping, not undo it.

But if your Erubis don't understand `<%==`, or if you use ERB, not Erubis, then sorry, I don't know any other solution except of what you said: disable html escape for entire file and use `h` everywhere you do need escaping.

*FYI, in Rails for this also there are special helpers `raw` and `String#html_safe`, but as I can see they are part of ActiveSupport and not available in Sinatra.*

Answer (score 5):

Just to add some tips. Erubis has ability to escape (sanitize) expression. Erubis::Eruby class act as the following:

```
<%= expr %> - not escaped.
<%== expr %> - escaped.
<%=== expr %> - out to $stderr.
<%==== expr %> - ignored.
```

[Source](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.02.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want this way:

Web.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'erubis'
set :erb, :escape_html => true

get '/hi' do
  @model = Hash.new()
  @model[:person] = "<b>World</b>"
  erb :hello
end
```

Layout.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= @title %></title>
</head>
<body>
  <%== yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello.erb:

```
<div>
  <p>Hello, <%= @model[:person] %>!</p>
  <p>Hello, <%== @model[:person] %>!</p>
</div>
```